# How to clear a vim register (vi/ex buffer)?

Tags: macro, register, original-vi

In the ex linage of editors, one can append to a register(vim)/buffer(ex,vi) by specifying the register name in uppercase. As an example

```
g/pat/y A
```

will append every line match `pat` to register `a`. But if `a` already has content, it will need to be cleared first.

**How?**

In vim, one can do `let @a = ''`. But this depends on having a vim compiled with the expression evaluation feature `+eval`. One can also do `qaq`, to record nothing into `a`, but recording is disabled while executing a register, inside mappings or in `:normal`, so it does not lend itself to automating.

vi/ex has no `let`, and no `q` or 'recording' equivalent , so how is buffers(registers) cleared in practical use?

To my disappointment, `:0y a` put line 1 in `a`, so the only way I can gleam is doing `"ay$` *on an empty line.* (EDIT: Apparently there is a discrepancy in how y$ works on empty lines between vim and vi)

Anything better?

Comment: What's wrong with `+eval`? If one does any "automating", he certainly should have it. Otherwise, use `qaq` interactively.

Comment: @Matt I'm asking how this was done in ex/vi, which has append to register functionality but no `+eval` or `q`

Comment: `"ay$` in an nvi does not clear the buffer for me. I suppose the easiest is to restart ex/vi, if you for some reason do not want to use vim.

Comment: @ChristianBrabandt I only tested that in vim. Curiously, in busybox vi, `"ay$` yanks until newline if the line is not empty, but yanks the newline if it is. What does it do in nvi, is it just a noop?

Comment: This works in Vim. Does it do in Vi too? `0"ayh`

Comment: @Matt it yanks a newline in busybox vi

Comment: And if `gg"ayh`?

Comment: newline again :)

Comment: TTBOMK Busybox has its own Vi clone. So it looks like Busybox problem to me.

Comment: Well, `"ayh` on first column will clear `a` in vile. Can't check any other clones, elvis wouldn't run because of some font issue I can't be bother to look into, and nvi has no package for my distro

Comment: @Matt seems we have an answer, would you like to do the honors?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So it turns out that all Vi clones are, well, different. For example, <kbd>0</kbd><kbd>"</kbd><kbd>a</kbd><kbd>y</kbd><kbd>h</kbd> clears register "a" in Vim, but not in Elvis; while <kbd>0</kbd><kbd>"</kbd><kbd>a</kbd><kbd>d</kbd><kbd>0</kbd> works in Elvis, but not in Vim.

As Busybox seems to ship "Vi" of its own, you have no other choice than to experiment and to find the right keys yourself.